# ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [ 4 16149]

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, data-science

Hi I'm new to scikit learn and data science in general. I am running into the above issue while trying to retrieve the most informative features from my vectorizer. My code (edited to reflect @Gang's comment):

```
values = dataset.data
word_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', stop_words=custom_stop_words)
trainset = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(values)
tags = ['dem','rep','dem','rep']
tags = np.array(tags)
trainset = trainset.toarray()

word_svm = svm.LinearSVC()
word_svm.fit(trainset, tags)


def most_informative_feature_for_binary_classification(vectorizer, classifier, n=10):
class_labels = classifier.classes_
feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
topn_class1 = sorted(zip(classifier.coef_[0], feature_names))[:n]
topn_class2 = sorted(zip(classifier.coef_[0], feature_names))[-n:]

for coef, feat in topn_class1:
    print class_labels[0], coef, feat

print

for coef, feat in reversed(topn_class2):
    print class_labels[1], coef, feat


most_informative_feature_for_binary_classification(word_vectorizer, word_svm)
```

Terminal output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "classification.py", line 251, in <module>
word_svm.fit(trainset, tags)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/classes.py", line 205, in fit
dtype=np.float64, order="C")
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 520, in check_X_y
check_consistent_length(X, y)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 176, in check_consistent_length
"%s" % str(uniques))
ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [    4 16149]
```

I'd appreciate any and all help on this matter. If I haven't presented enough information, please let me know. Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: The fit method expects an X array (trainset here) of dimensions (n, f) where f is the number of features (the number of words in the count vectorizer) and n is the number of documents. This is a supervised method, so it also must take a y (tags here, also called target) vector of length n (the number of documents). It looks like what is happening is that the count vectorizer is spitting out 16,149 documents (possibly # of words?), how many docs are in values?

Comment: If you were expecting 4, maybe try `word_vectorizer.fit_transform([values])`

Answer (score 0):

Here is where it failed - both parameters should be the same type -- array

```
word_svm.fit(trainset, tags)
```

tags is not an array, should be converted to array

```
tags = ['dem','rep','dem','rep']
```

You can use print to see if they are the same type

```
print type(tags)
print type(trainset)
```

The following code is written with text editor without running, not gurantee to work, but you got the idea, I might be wrong about converting to array, List is fine.

Your trainset is properly contains invalid data, replace

```
word_svm.fit(trainset, tags)
```

with this:

```
trainset_good, trainset_bad = trainset_check(trainset, tags)
print 'Bad data\n'
print trainset_bad
if len(trainset_good)==0:
   print 'No good valid data found, exit'
   sys.exit(1)

# use good data
word_svm.fit(trainset_good, tags)
```

Add this function to the code

```
def trainset_check(trainset, tags):
    trainset_good = []
    trainset_bad = []
    if not trainset:
        print 'Err trainset is empty'
        return trainset_good, trainset_bad
    if not tags:
        print 'Err - tags empty'
        return trainset_good, trainset_bad
    if len(trainset)==0:
        print 'Err trainset is empty'
        return trainset_good, trainset_bad
    if len(tags)==0:
        print 'Err tags empty'
        return trainset_good, trainset_bad
    for item in trainset:
        if len(item) != len(tags):
            print 'Error - trainset item is not the same length as tags'
            print item
            trainset_bad.append(item)
            # skip to next
            continue
        # filter out None type
        item_new = filter(None, item)
        if len(item_new) != len(tags):
            print 'Error - trainset item is not the same length as tags'
            # bad trainset data, skip to next
            print item
            trainset_bad.append(item)
            continue
         trainset_good.append(item)
    return trainset_good, trainset_bad
```

Comment: Hi I edited my code to reflect your changes but I'm still running into the same error.

Comment: @salols, if you found the new edit does not help, I might be on the wrong track.